# E-Commerce Concurrency for limited inventory

Tags: java, spring, concurrency, redis, e-commerce

I have concurrency issue in my e-commerce application.

we have product table where we maintain inventory ex. product Name, SKU, inventory, status etc.

Application is deployed in cluster. I did not face any issue while i was using single machine, now due to load i need to deploy application on multiple machines.

How can i handle concurrency, where we have limited inventory and multiple user's are trying to buy the same product, JVM locking will not work in cluster environment.

Can i use Redis or hazelcast as distributed locking or any other good approach i can use ?

Comment: You have a table. Where is your table. RBDMS? Then `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` is the answer. Naming random technologies is not productive. Externalising the lock from the master data is a really good way to get corrupted master data.

Comment: Redis support a simple [INCR](https://redis.io/commands/INCR) command that you can use as shared distributed counter